# Bootstrap text align top center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to align text `top` and `center` (for example) using bootstrap.

I have tried using:

```
<label class=text-align-top text-align-center></label>
```

It does not seem to work.

Comment: did you mean you tried `<label class="text-align: top; text-align: center"></label>` or is this a serious try you made... and based on what tutorial or suggestion...?

Comment: I am currently using `'text-align-top'` and it is working in my app. So i am looking for a bootstrap way to align it center+top. If it does not exist i guess i ll stick to css

Comment: your css does the same thing as mine by the way

Comment: check out my answer...

Comment: I am going to try it now, strange i swear i saw a class for `text-align-...` online, cannt find it in my css files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you probably wanted to have this instead:

```
<label class="text-align-top text-align-center"></label>
```

(adding quotes around the CSS class names)

This would assume, however, that you have defined both, `text-align-top` and `text-align-center` classes in CSS, as no such classes exist in Twitter-Bootstrap.

If you want to do this the Twitter-Bootstrap-way, you can simply use the [Alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#type-alignment), which will take care of horizontal alignments. In your case you'd use `text-center`.

There are no vertical alignment classes in twitter-bootstrap, so you're going to have to set it up yourself using `vertical-align: middle;` on your targeted element, or create your custom CSS class having that, ie...

CSS:

```
.vertical-align-top {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

HTML (with twitter-bootstrap):

```
<label class="vertical-align-top text-center"></label>
```

Comment: @KaanBurakSener I was about to edit it myself, so must have clicked the wrong button, then I realised you did have a valid edit, sorry about that, mate...

Comment: @webeno `style="vertical-align: middle;" class="text-center"` this did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @ShareYourKnowledge I'm happy I could be of help ;)

Answer (score 1):

add this **`style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"`**
to your tag attribiutes